# I want implement face recognition as part of authentication

Tags: api, authentication, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

Currently I am using [Microsoft Face api](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/face/) to match photo during login 
(capturing using webcam while login and compared with already uploaded photo).

Issue I am facing is people can use photos from mobile or some photos to share account.

Is there any full proof way to verify face?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... what you mean is that they are putting photos in front of the webcam? How is your image capture process implemented: they choose a photo? Or you select a frame from the webcam?

Comment: They click to match, I select frame from webcam..
Yes, they are putting photos in front of webcam while matching photo.

Comment: And the face on the photo is recognized as a valid face, then compared to the known ones?

Comment: Yes the photo from profile and from webcam is matched..
I want way to find the photo captured is of real person or not..

Answer (score 0):

Based on our exchanges in comment, the problem is:

- Users may be using photos of someone else in front of the camera to try to be validated by Face API.
- Those photos are detected as valid faces, not photos

Sadly, it looks like there is nothing in the API at the moment allowing to detect this problem.

But you are not the only one facing it, I found on Uservoice a topic about the same problem: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/430315-face-api/suggestions/31986709-a-way-to-determine-if-the-image-is-a-photo-or-a-re

I already voted on it, I suggest that you do the same.

Comment: Found one service that does Spoof detection.. but expensive..
https://trueface.ai/tutorials  "Test our API in 120 seconds"
https://www.youtube.com/embed/vqFew7aaCVQ

Still looking for other options.

Comment: My reply was about Microsoft Face API, maybe there are other solutions elsewhere yes